# Route to take for accessing data when using two databases

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql

I am trying to create an e-commerce site and I need to make a decision on witch direction to take for creating the account management.I have two databases one is `ASPNETDB.MDF` and the other is `ComputerStore.mdf`, and I am using LINQ to SQL for accessing the data in `ComputerStore` so far.

My problem is that I do not know exactly how to move forward.

On one hand I have the Membership API with witch I am familiar and I could use that to access the data in `ASPNETDB.MDF`, but I do not know if this can be mixed with the current LINQ-to-SQL model because at some point when I create the shopping cart table I will need the user ID for each row.

On the other hand I could try adding tables from the `ASPNETDB.MDF` to the LINQ-to-SQL model created based on the `ComputerStore.mdf` tables again I do not know if mixing two databases in the same LINQ-to-SQL model will work well.

If there is any other option please let me know. If not what route should I take?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you *must* use a separate database for the membership tables, then you'll simply have to loosely couple the user id across the databases. Then to access the membership database, simply create its own LINQ to SQL model.

This will allow you to perform CRUD on both databases, and you can gather the user id from the membership model when necessary to place the loosely coupled id into the shopping cart table.

Answer (score 1):

You can have both databases separate or you can mix them in one (I prefer to have it separate, because I hate to mix membership database format and nomenclature with mine)

[Here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-vb) you have a little tutorial to deploy the **Membership** database into any SQL Server instance. After that, create your own tables into that database. If you want to have the relationship between `YourTable_UserID` and the `ID` from the `Users` table, you can. Remember that **Membership** uses [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier) for IDs.